# Simplify expressions with logarithm, exponent, imaginary number

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions

By [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/566856/is-sum-n-1-infty-frac-sinnxn-continuous) we know $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(nx)}n = \frac{\pi-x}2\,,$$
when $x \in (0, 2\pi)\,.$

However,

**Input:**

```
Sum[Sin[n x]/n, {n, ∞}]
% ~ FullSimplify ~ (Assumptions -> 0 < x < 2 π && x ∈ Reals)
```

**Output:**

$\frac{1}{2} i \left(\log \left(1-e^{i x}\right)-\log \left(e^{-i x} \left(-1+e^{i x}\right)\right)\right)\\
\frac{1}{2} i \left(\log \left(1-e^{i x}\right)-\log \left(1-e^{-i x}\right)\right)$

Those above is not the form I want as $\frac{\pi -x}{2}\,.$

I have tried `ComplexExpand` and `PowerExpand`, but it seems no use.

How to get it?

Be grateful for any help!

---

---

### Conclusion

@Michael gives the fantastic **mathematical** solution.

@Akku14 gives the "no thinking needed" way, e.g. below.

---

### Examples

**1.** To solve $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(nx)}n\,,$

**Input:**

```
Sum[Sin[n x]/n, {n, ∞}];
% // Exp // #^(2/I) & // PowerExpand // FullSimplify // #^(I/2) & // Log // PowerExpand[#, Assumptions -> 0 <= x <= 2π] & // FullSimplify[#, 0 < x <= 2π] &
```

**Output:**

$\displaystyle \frac{\pi-x}{2}$

**2.** To solve $\displaystyle 2\pi n \int_0^{\frac\pi2} \frac1{\cos^2(x)+n^6\sin^2(x)}\,dx\,,$

**Input:**

```
2 n π Integrate[1/(Cos[x]^2 + n^6 Sin[x]^2), {x, 0, π/2}];
% // #^(2/I) & // #^(I/2) & // PowerExpand
```

**Output:**

$\displaystyle \frac{\pi^2}{n^2}$

**3.** Cyclotomic.

**Input:**

```
n = 5;
cy = Product[x - E^((2 π I k)/n), {k, Select[Range[n], CoprimeQ[#, n] &]}]
```

**Output:**

$\left(x-e^{-\frac{2i\pi}5}\right) \left(x-e^{\frac{2i\pi}5}\right) \left(x-e^{-\frac{4i\pi}5}\right) \left(x-e^{\frac{4i\pi}5}\right)$

**Input:**

```
Cyclotomic[n, x]

cy // Exp // FullSimplify // Log // PowerExpand    (*Method 1*)

Collect[cy, x, FullSimplify]                       (*Method 2*)
```

**Same outputs:**

$x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$

Comment: Shouldn't a new question be an actual new question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way I've found is to apply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus:

```
Integrate[Evaluate@D[Sum[Sin[n x]/n, {n, ∞}], x], {x, Pi, x}]
```

Another approach is to apply a trig. function, simplify, apply the inverse function, and simplify again.  The problem here is that [`ArcTan`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArcTan.html) and [`ArcCot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArcCot.html) both have ranges of `-Pi/2` to `Pi/2`, which are not suitable for the solution.  So we can translate the solution to the appropriate range, and then translate back:

```
(FullSimplify[
    Sum[Sin[n x]/n, {n, ∞}] /. x -> Pi - u // Tan // 
     TrigExpand
    ] // FullSimplify[ArcTan[#], -Pi < u < Pi] &) /. u -> Pi - x
(*  (π - x)/2  *)
```

There are other ways to tease out the answer, which have a mathematical fault even though they get the right answer.  For instance:

```
Normal@Series[Sum[Sin[n x]/n, {n, ∞}], {x, Pi, 100}]

Sum[Sin[n x]/n, {n, ∞}] // Cot // TrigExpand // 
 FullSimplify[Pi/2 - ArcTan[#], -Pi < x < Pi] &
```

Comment: @user52778 The number `Pi` is in the interval `0 < x < 2 Pi` and when the upper limit `x == Pi`, the answer should be zero.  If you want a solution over a different interval, change the initial point (lower limit) to be the corresponding number in the interval.

Comment: @ooo The "full easiest way" is $s(x) = s(a) + \int_a^x s'(t)\;dt$ (by the FTC), where I used $a = \pi$ and the fact that the sum $s(\pi)$ is obviously zero since all the terms are zero.  Is that what you mean?  Or are you worried about whether to pick the interval $(0, 2\pi)$ or some other one?  (The FTC way works over any interval for which the sum $s(x)$ is differentiable. The intervals are clear from the result of `Sum[]`, i.e. the endpoints are where $1-e^{ix} = 0$.)

Comment: @ooo Do you mean applying the identity $\log z = \log |z| + i\,\arg z$ to the result of the sum to derive $(\pi -x)/2$?

Comment: @ooo For the sum, use Euler's identity $\sin nx = (e^{inx} - e^{-inx})/(2i)$ to convert the sum into two log series $\log(1-u)=\sum u^n/n$, with $u = e^{ix}, e^{-ix}$. If you're unfamiliar with complex analysis, it might seem a little tough going. -- Ref for the complex log: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Complex_logarithm -- Geometric pic for $\arg(1-e^{ix})=-(\pi-x)/2$: http://i.stack.imgur.com/HD6xE.png

Comment: So you gave the "complex analysis" way to get the result directly, which **far faster than the FTC method**! Amazing to me! I'll remember this way. But what does it have to do with the FTC? Could you show me the **whole calculation progress of FTC way**? Thanks~♥

Comment: @ooo Just differentiate the formula returned by `Sum[]` like this `ds = D[1/2 I (-Log[1 - E^(-I x)] + Log[1 - E^(I x)]), x]` using the chain rule and the derivative of log.  Then add the fractions, like this, `Simplify[ds]`.  You get `-1/2`.  Then integrate. Is that what you want?  The "FTC way" is just a way to transform the result of `Sum[]`. It's not a different way to find the sum.

Comment: Finally, I realized that it was beyond the realm of **real analysis** to take the `Sum[]` derivative directly. Thank you very much for your patience and perfect answers!! ♥

Answer (score 2):

Here another simple, quite mechanical way.

Straightforword apply operators that are suited to simplify the expression, simplify and later apply the inverse operator.

```
t1 = Sum[Sin[n x]/n, {n, \[Infinity]}]

(*      1/2 I (Log[1 - E^(I x)] - Log[E^(-I x) (-1 + E^(I x))])     *)

t2 = t1 // Exp

(*     E^(1/2 I (Log[1 - E^(I x)] - Log[E^(-I x) (-1 + E^(I x))]))     *)

t3 = t2 // FullSimplify

(*     (1 - E^(-I x))^(-(I/2)) (1 - E^(I x))^(I/2)     *)

t4 = t3 // #^(2/I) &

(*     ((1 - E^(-I x))^(-(I/2)) (1 - E^(I x))^(I/2))^(-2 I)     *)

t5 = t4 // PowerExpand[#, Assumptions -> 0 <= x <= 2 Pi] &

(*     E^(4 \[Pi] Floor[
    1/2 + Re[Log[1 - E^(-I x)]]/(4 \[Pi]) - Re[Log[1 - E^(I x)]]/(
    4 \[Pi])])/(1 - E^(-I x)) - E^(
    I x + 4 \[Pi] Floor[
    1/2 + Re[Log[1 - E^(-I x)]]/(4 \[Pi]) - Re[Log[1 - E^(I x)]]/(
    4 \[Pi])])/(1 - E^(-I x))     *)

t6 = t5 // FullSimplify[#, 0 <= x <= 2 Pi] &

(*     -E^(I x)     *)

t7 = t6 // #^(I/2) &

(*     (-E^(I x))^(I/2)     *)

t8 = t7 // PowerExpand[#, Assumptions -> 0 <= x <= 2 Pi] &

 (*     E^(-(\[Pi]/2) - x/2 - \[Pi] Floor[-(x/(2 \[Pi]))])     *)

t9 = t8 // FullSimplify[#, 0 <= x <= 2 Pi] &

(*     E^(-(\[Pi]/2) - x/2 + \[Pi] Ceiling[x/(2 \[Pi])])     *)

t10 = t9 // Log

(*     Log[E^(-(\[Pi]/2) - x/2 + \[Pi] Ceiling[x/(2 \[Pi])])]     *)

t11 = t10 // PowerExpand[#, Assumptions -> 0 <= x <= 2 Pi] &

(*     -(Pi/2) - x/2 + Pi Ceiling[x/(2 Pi)]     *)

t12 = t11 // FullSimplify[#, 0 < x <= 2 Pi] &

(*     (Pi - x)/2     *)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may like to proceed as follows. Here is your expression:

```
expr1 = Simplify[Sum[Sin[n x]/n, {n, 1, \[Infinity]}], 0 < x < 2 \[Pi]]

(*  1/2 I (-Log[1 - E^(-I x)] + Log[1 - E^(I x)]) *)
```

Mma does not collect logarithms by itself. I use for this purpose the function entitled collectLog:

```
collectLog[expr_] := Module[{rule1a, rule1b, rule2, g, a, b, x},
   rule1a = Log[a_] + Log[b_] -> Log[a*b];
   rule1b = Log[a_] - Log[b_] -> Log[a/b];
   rule2 = x_*Log[a_] -> Log[a^x];
   g[x_] := x /. rule1a /. rule1b /. rule2;
   FixedPoint[g, expr]
   ];
```

It should be applied to the second element of the expression. Further the resulting subexpression is worth simplifying:

```
expr2 = MapAt[Simplify[collectLog[#]] &, expr1, {2}]

(*   1/2 I Log[-E^(I x)]  *)
```

Now Mma should be instructed that `-1==E^I*Pi` and that `Log[E^a]==a`:

```
expr2 /. -E^a_ -> E^(a + I*\[Pi]) /. Log[E^a_] -> a // Expand

(*  -(\[Pi]/2) - x/2  *)
```

Done.

Have fun!